# Get data from database to listview android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Hi there i'm trying to get data from my sqlite database to a listview. I already tried several ways but gives me always the error. (And yes, i already tried to fix the code of that line, unsuccessfully).
The Code:

```
        Cursor cursor = db.getAllmeds();

        String[] list = null;
        int i = 0;
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for (cursor.moveToFirst();!cursor.isAfterLast();cursor.moveToNext()){
            list[i]=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("medicamentos_desig"));
            i+=1;
        }

        int to[] = {R.id.listView1};

        db.close();
        final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.medicamentos,cursor,list,to,0);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {

                Cursor listCursor = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

                String id = listCursor.getString(listCursor.getColumnIndex("medicamentos_id"));

                Intent passIntent = new Intent(arg1.getContext(),Editar.class);
                passIntent.putExtra("id", id);
                passIntent.putExtra("tipo", tipo);
                passIntent.putExtra("accao", "update");
                startActivity(passIntent);
            }

        });
```

error log:

```
     05-29 18:33:32.653: E/AndroidRuntime(341): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
     05-29 18:33:32.653: E/AndroidRuntime(341):     at admed.Listar$1.onItemClick(Listar.java:55)
```

Comment: Include the details of the error.

Comment: already posted the error log

Comment: @JoaoCorreia : what is line number 55 in Listar.java ?

Comment: listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

Comment: @JoaoCorreia : why you are passing ListView id in `int to[] = {R.id.listView1};` just pass View it to which you want to show data like TextView,EditText,.. and add only colums in `list` which you want to show in TextView like `list=new String["medicamentos_desig"];`

Comment: to put it on the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

in here:

```
String[] list = null;  //<<<
```

you will need to initialize `list` Array  before adding elements.

```
 cursor.moveToFirst();
 list=new String[cursor.getCount()];//<<<initialize Array here with cursor Count
 .....
```